# Cannot read property 'variable' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I am navigating an object that contains an array of objects.

When I use chrome's js developer console I can grab the title property from the first item in the array i.e.

```
hello.example.array[0].title
```

this returns the title (only in the js developer console). However when I write a script to do this for me suddenly I receive this response:

```
Cannot read property 'array' of undefined
```

here is an example of my js

```
var theTitle = hello.example.array[0].title;
console.log(theTitle);
```

**Why does the console find it correctly when my js does not?**

Comment: Is it possible to create a fiddle so that it would be much easier to help

Comment: It is possibe that you are making a asyn call, which means that your array is not ready yet. Just a guess.

Comment: Do you have object instantiation?

Comment: `hello.example` is apparently undefined.

Comment: I think you tried to access `hello.example.array[0].title` before it was set, and when you access it with the Console, all your JS is already executed and the variable is thus set. But it is impossible to say this for sure without seeing more code.

Comment: Is your js called before the document is ready? If it works in the console, seems like the dom has loaded and your array is populated.

Comment: Also,you could try setting the variable inside `$(document).ready`

Comment: No, better as early as possible, and in the global scope: outside `$(document).ready` for global scope and at the top of the script. @harsha

Comment: @11684 : thanks for the info.I am still learning :-)

Comment: @11684 Good thought, going to investigate more and get back to everyone.

Comment: Please post your code. Without seeing it, all we can do is guess.

Comment: @Barmar to be fair, the code is indeed already posted. the variable being set as shown above is all the code I am using, and the error I am receiving is indeed listed as well.

Comment: We need to see the context in which this code runs. The problem is most likely with the timing of assigning the variable and trying to read it. The error means that you're trying to read it before assigning it, or there's a problem with variable scopes.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, continuing to investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Barmar, I realized I needed to view how I was going about grabbing the 'title' property.

My solution was in the context of other code and how the object was being created in the first place.

Thanks all for the help!

---

***Edit 6 Years later:***
This post has some popularity so I thought I would update it with a more valid answer...

1. Make sure your JavaScript actually has the scope/context of the object to begin with.
2. The JS Console is able to return it because it is being executed after the code has run.. whereas the JavaScript in question might be trying to access the variable before it is set.

So check if you have the right scope/context and that the code is not trying to access a variable before it has been set.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the expression in question in the script view and then use the `Ctrl-Shift-E` shortcut to evaluate in the console. Or, copy-and-paste from the script view into the console. Or, hover over the last component of the expression in the script view to see the value. In either case, you will most likely find that you've mistyped something, or are executing the script in a different context than that in which you are evaluating the expression in the console, etc.